# The Kaspersky Internet Security safelink indicator/URL Advisor icon is missing?

Tags: security, anti-virus, kaspersky

I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security 2018. When I google something, I usually rely on Kaspersky Internet Security safelink indicator [image: KasperskySafeLinkIndicatorSymbol] to prevent clicking the virus link.

But recently when I google, I see it missing like the image below
[image: KasperskySafeLinkIndicator]
Is there anyway I can force it show?

**Edit:** Here is my Kaspersky Add-on information:
Kaspersky Protection 5.1.94.28d-20180412184251
[image: KasperskyAddon]

**Edit2:** I just realize "safelink indicator" can be called: Kaspersky URL Advisor icon. It looks like this is a bug:

[URL Advisor icon missing in web broswer](https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/320806-url-advisor-icon-missing-in-web-broswer/)

[Green sheild for safe websites not showing up anymore.](https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/401222-green-sheild-for-safe-websites-not-showing-up-anymore/)

Comment: @dsstorefile1: Thanks, I checked the addons and put the addons information in the question.

Comment: Note that I turn on the ad-block of Kaspersky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL Advisor icon missing is a bug, so we have 2 solutions:

Solution 1: Wait for Kaspersky to fix the bug in the new version.

Solution 2: Use this alternative method to check the link: copy and paste any links to this website https://virusdesk.kaspersky.com/ to check whether the link is safe or not.